# which fields fit the most for applying anomaly detection under uncertainty,?

Tags: large-data, anomaly-detection

If an outlirness/outlying degree can be attached to each data point, then what are the fields (with open datasets) which may benefit the most from such uncertainty?
I am also a bit restricted with the nature of data as I am working on a statistical anomaly detection algorithm.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Fraud detection. Network intrusion detection.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the statistical approach I am using is not roper for temporal data as Fraud detection. Regarding the network intrusion detection data, will you please elaborate a bit your point of how it is going to be useful in such situation?